# How can I fix "Object doesn't support this property or method" The code seems correct but won't run

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Show_Inventory()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")

sh.Cells.Clear

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").Range("B:B").Copy sh.Range("A1")

sh.Range("B1").Value = "Purchase"
sh.Range("C1").Value = "Sale"
sh.Range("D1").Value = "Available Stock"
sh.Range("E1").Value = "Stock Value"

Dim lr As Long

lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))


If lr > 1 Then

    sh.Range("B2").Value = "=SUMIFS(Sale_Purchase!D:D,Sale_Purchase!B:B,Inventory!A2,Sale_Purchase!C:C,""Purchase"")"
    sh.Range("C2").Value = "=SUMIFS(Sale_Purchase!D:D,Sale_Purchase!B:B,Inventory!A2,Sale_Purchase!C:C,""Sale"")"
    sh.Range("D2").Value = "=B2-C2"
    sh.Range("E2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Product_Master!B:C,2,FALSE) *D2"
    
    If lr > 2 Then
        sh.Range("B2:E" & lr).FillDown
    End If
    
    sh.Calculate
    
End If


sh.UsedRange.Copy
sh.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Dim inv_Display As Worksheet
Set inv_Display = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory_Display")

inv_Display.Cells.Clear

If Me.txtSearch.Value <> "" Then
sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, "*" & Me.txtSearch.Value & "*"
End If
sh.UsedRange.Copy inv_Display.Range("A1")


'''''''''''''''''''''' show data

    lr = Application.WorksheetFunction(inv_Display.Range("A:A"))

If lr = 1 Then lr = 2

With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnWidths = "150,0,0,80,0"
    .RowSource = inv_Display.Name & "!A2:E" & lr
End With
```

I believe the cause of the error is in the last segment of the code (Show data). I have tried removing it and the code worked. This code is for an inventory management system. I believe the most probable cause of the error is the definition of the (lr)

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) please [edit] your question and include your code as text formatted as code block. Also include in which line you get the error. • Note that very obviously the code seems **not correct** if it throws an unhandled exception.

Comment: Nothing is clear in your question... You pasted a piece of code, you do not mention on which code line the error is raised and your picture does also not show any yellow code line, in order to understand something about the error. Should we deduce that the line `.RowSource = inv_Display.Name & "!A2:E" & lr` is the problematic one? Only based on the fact you try showing us how `lr` is calculated...

Comment: I fully understand your comments but unfortunately i dont know where the error is... it just wont run and it wouldn't give me the option to "Debug"

Comment: It used to run before i added The part I put in the Post...

Comment: If this error occurs “object doesn't support this property or method” it will show you which line of code the error is. • Please remove the picture of your code and add the code as text. Please make clear wich part you added and *where* exactly in the code you added it. Do this explanations in your original question. Not in comments!

Comment: Should I post the full code? or just the Part that was recently added?

Comment: You should post the **relevant part** of the code that is necessary to reproduce your issue (see [mcve]) and you need to tell in which line the error occurs. Otherwise it is impossible to help you. Pictures of code are not useful.

Comment: Please, try running the code line by line, pressing F8 and see on which line it stops.

Comment: In fact `WorksheetFunction(Range("A:A"))` has no any meaning? What do you want by using it? You maybe need `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))`... Even if, the last row on the column should be returned in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
'''''''''''''''''''''' show data

    lr = Application.WorksheetFunction(inv_Display.Range("A:A"))
```

The second time you define lr you miss the actual name of the function you want to call.

The error means that the Application object does not support the WorksheetFunction() method because it is not a method but a collection of functions and you have to pick one:)

Comment: so what exactly should I do?

Comment: @IssaNabihMousa That is actually the question that we cannot answer. What did you expect `lr = Application.WorksheetFunction(inv_Display.Range("A:A"))` to do? What was your intention with this line? This `lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(inv_Display.Range("A:A"))`? As you did the first time you set `lr`?